Connecting two trees with a line, with tikz
I have two trees one next to the other. Some of the nodes should be connected. The code for connection nodes is breaking compilation, and I don't get any lines connecting the nodes between the trees.
\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering

% Tree 1
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  every node/.style={circle, draw, minimum size=6mm},
  level/.style={sibling distance=25mm/#1},
  level 1/.style={level distance=10mm},
  level 2/.style={level distance=15mm}
]
\node {1}
  child {node {2}
    child {node {4}}
    child {node {5}}
  }
  child {node {3}
    child {node {6}}
    child {node {7}}
  };
\end{tikzpicture}
\hspace{2cm} % Adjust the horizontal space between trees
% Tree 2
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  every node/.style={circle, draw, minimum size=6mm},
  level/.style={sibling distance=25mm/#1},
  level 1/.style={level distance=10mm},
  level 2/.style={level distance=15mm}
]
\node {A}
  child {node {B}
    child {node {D}}
    child {node {E}}
  }
  child {node {C}
    child {node {F}}
    child {node {G}}
  };
% Edges between trees (bipartite connections)
\draw[->] (1) -- (6);
\draw[->] (2) -- (B);
\draw[->] (3) -- (C);
\draw[->] (4) -- (D);
\draw[->] (5) -- (E);
\draw[->] (6) -- (F);
\draw[->] (7) -- (G);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

Errors I get for all the arrows:

 
‪./main.tex, 613‬
See the pgf package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.613 \draw[->] (1)
                    -- (6);
This error message was generated by an \errmessage
command, so I can't give any explicit help.
Pretend that you're Hercule Poirot: Examine all clues,
and deduce the truth by order and method.

What is wrong? How do I add these arrows?
EDIT: Adding node names does not help.
Errors are, after I added node names:
Label `eq:sum_l1' multiply defined.

 
‪./output.aux‬
You have used the same label more than once. Check that each \label{...} labels only one item.
Learn more
Label `eq:sum_l2' multiply defined.

 
‪./output.aux‬
You have used the same label more than once. Check that each \label{...} labels only one item.
Learn more
Label `eq:xe_nonnegative' multiply defined.

 
‪./output.aux‬
You have used the same label more than once. Check that each \label{...} labels only one item.
Learn more
`!h' float specifier changed to `!ht'.

 
‪./main.tex‬
The float specifier 'h' is too strict of a demand for LaTeX to place your float in a nice way here. Try relaxing it by using 'ht', or even 'htbp' if necessary. If you want to try keep the float here anyway, check out the float package.
Learn more
Package pgf Warning: Returning node center instead of a point on node border. Did you specify a point identical to the center of node ``A''? on input line 613.

 
‪./main.tex, 613‬
Package pgf Warning: Returning node center instead of a point on node border. Did you specify a point identical to the center of node ``1''? on input line 613.


I think you forgot to name your nodes.

Thanks for the comment. It does clear previous errors and adds new ones. Still no line drawn.

Welcome! You need remember picture if you want to reference the nodes after the picture is finished. By default, the names are all local to that picture. Please post compilable code rather than snippets.

You can put an entire tikzpicture inside a savebox and put that savebox inside another tikzpicture (node).

Thanks. Apologies, it is a large document with loads of packages in the beginning, that's why I overlooked the rest of the code.

Two issues:

You haven't named the nodes, as pointed out in a comment.
Nodes are local to tikzpictures.

Solutions:

Name the nodes.
Either use remember picture or put the trees into a single tikzpicture.

For example,
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}    
\begin{figure}[ht!]% this is what `h!` becomes as `h!` isn't allowable
  \centering
  
  % Tree 1
  \begin{tikzpicture}[
    every node/.style={circle, draw, minimum size=6mm},
    level/.style={sibling distance=25mm/#1},
    level 1/.style={level distance=10mm},
    level 2/.style={level distance=15mm}
    ]
    \node (1) {1}
    child {node (2) {2}
      child {node (4) {4}}
      child {node (5) {5}}
    }
    child {node (3) {3}
      child {node (6) {6}}
      child {node (7) {7}}
    };
    % Tree 2
    \begin{scope}[
      xshift=50mm,
      every node/.style={circle, draw, minimum size=6mm},
      level/.style={sibling distance=25mm/#1},
      level 1/.style={level distance=10mm},
      level 2/.style={level distance=15mm}
      ]
      \node (A) {A}
      child {node (B) {B}
        child {node (D){D}}
        child {node (E){E}}
      }
      child {node (C){C}
        child {node (F){F}}
        child {node (G){G}}
      };
    \end{scope}   
    % Edges between trees (bipartite connections)
    \draw[->] (1) -- (6);
    \draw[->] (2) -- (B);
    \draw[->] (3) -- (C);
    \draw[->] (4) -- (D);
    \draw[->] (5) -- (E);
    \draw[->] (6) -- (F);
    \draw[->] (7) -- (G);
    
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}

or
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}    
\begin{figure}[ht!]
  \centering
  
  % Tree 1
  \begin{tikzpicture}[
    remember picture,
    baseline=(1),
    every node/.style={circle, draw, minimum size=6mm},
    level/.style={sibling distance=25mm/#1},
    level 1/.style={level distance=10mm},
    level 2/.style={level distance=15mm}
    ]
    \node (1) {1}
    child {node (2) {2}
      child {node (4) {4}}
      child {node (5) {5}}
    }
    child {node (3) {3}
      child {node (6) {6}}
      child {node (7) {7}}
    };
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \hspace{20mm}
  % Tree 2
  \begin{tikzpicture}[
    remember picture,
    xshift=2cm,
    overlay,
    baseline=(A),
    every node/.style={circle, draw, minimum size=6mm},
    level/.style={sibling distance=25mm/#1},
    level 1/.style={level distance=10mm},
    level 2/.style={level distance=15mm}
    ]
    \node (A) {A}
    child {node (B) {B}
      child {node (D){D}}
      child {node (E){E}}
    }
    child {node (C){C}
      child {node (F){F}}
      child {node (G){G}}
    };
    % Edges between trees (bipartite connections)
    \draw[->] (1) -- (6);
    \draw[->] (2) -- (B);
    \draw[->] (3) -- (C);
    \draw[->] (4) -- (D);
    \draw[->] (5) -- (E);
    \draw[->] (6) -- (F);
    \draw[->] (7) -- (G);
    
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}

Not sure the output is what's intended, but it does compile.
